# C# .net Вывод некоторых строк из БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, фильтрация

Доброго времени суток, взялся за C#, сделал простой вывод данных из таблицы на страницу.

--

В таблице есть несколько строк и поле "Date" (дата добавления записи).
А в представлении цикл foreach, который выводит все строки.

--

Мне нужно вывести только те строчки, которые совпадают с датой, например "1.11.2017"

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div class="row line">
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Road</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Time</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Places</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Price</div>

    </div>
}
```

Как можно реализовать самым простым способом?

Comment: фильтровать в момент формирования запроса в БД

Comment: какой тип имеет поле Time?datetime?

Comment: Time - time, 
Date - Date

Comment: А фильтрация только по дате?

Comment: Ну да, там будет форма, при выборе даты, показать записи в этот день.

Comment: Фильтрацию в таких случаях обычно делают в действии контроллера, а во вьюшку передают уже готовый, отфильтрованный результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Date==new DateTime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToList())
{
    <div class="row line">
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Road</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Time</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Places</div>
        <div class="column col-xs-3">@item.Price</div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Во, то что надо! немного не до конца получается я писал, думал совсем не то.
Благодарю!

Comment: Это все необходимо делать в контроллере

Answer (score 4):

Фильтрация обычно делается в действии контроллера, а во вьюку передаётся уже подготовленный для отображения результат.

Для фильтрации используюя linq обычно применяется такой синтаксис:

```
var items = db.NameOfEntytySet.Where(x=>x.Date==dateToFilter).OrderBy(x=>x.Date);
```

В примере выше я запись получаю из базы данных, но её можно получить с любого списка путём `list.Where(x=>x.Date==dateToFilter)`. list имплементирует интерфейс IEnumerable. Так же в примере выше я отсортировал записи по дате.

Comment: Ваш, вариант немного сложней, но в будущем учту) Спасибо!